# PHP VSCode Xdebug Error::listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9111

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm sure the port doesn't been used before I run debug (press `F5`) I have kill the process which using 9111, but it also can not run and tip me the same error. I have also tried to change the port, got the same error.

lanch.JSON

```
{
// 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。 
// 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。
// 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        //"hostname": "192.168.0.104",

        //"localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 9111
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        //"program": "${file}",
        //"cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9111
    }
]
```

}

PHP.ini

```
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9111
xdebug.client_port = 9111
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.auto_trace = Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace = Off
xdebug.var_display_max_children=128
xdebug.var_display_max_data=512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=15
```

After press `F5`, my VSCode shows this. The browser can't open,

[image]

then I click the foot list for xdebug:

[image]

When I click listen Xdebug, it shows an error:

[image]

Comment: So what URL are you trying to open in a browser? Show the address bar / browser screenshot of the page that you are trying to debug.

Answer (score 1):

1. Kill any process currently holding the port 9111. To do this, open a terminal(or CMD) as administrator

   a) netstat -ano | findstr :9111 (Windows)
   netstat -tunlp | grep 8080

   b) Stop the process, using Process ID found in the previous step.
   stop-process   (Windows)
   sudo kill -9
2. Then click Start Debugging(in VSCode) again.

Comment: Or change the port from 9111 to other port.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happens when you're using xdebug on remote server with vs code and suddenly vscode killed for some reason. so the remote server did not get kill message from server to not listen to the xdebug 9003 port.

Same happened with me and tried below command which worked for me.

```
kill -9 $(lsof -n -i:9003 -P)
```